# Android: Covertir path a File

Tags: android

Como convierto este path

> /storage/emulated/0/Download/images (10).jpg

que esta en String a File

Comment: Agregué una respuesta considerando una ruta de una base de datos que al parecer es lo que te interesa.=)

Comment: Tu siempre muy amable Elenasys te agradesco que me estes ayudando demasiado y estoy aprendiendo mucho gracias a tus aportes.

Comment: Personas como tu necesitamos en estos foros

Comment: Yo tambien ayudo con mis conocimientos pobres que tengo pero me sorprendes tu.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes ocupar lo siguiente:

```
Uri.fromFile(new File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/images(10).jpg")
```

o

```
File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/images(10).jpg");
```

Comment: entonces el File guarda de nuevo el path?

Comment: Si lo almacena en una instancia de File, para que lo piensas ocupar?

Comment: Amigo, si alguien a respondido a tus preguntas no olvides calificar, saludos.

Comment: El File se va a guardar en una Base de Datos Mysql

Comment: es correcto guardar un File en Mysql?

Comment: Si me explicas bien el contexto puedo ayudarte de una manera mas acertada, ¿Para que quieres guardar el file?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que mi app de android consiste en guardas imagenes en Mysql entonces por ejemplo yo condulto un folio corresponde a un producto la app muestra informacion de ese producto y aparte tiene que traer las imagenes

Comment: Lo que tienes que guardar es la imagen, no el file, ni la ruta de la imagen en el dispositivo

Comment: Hola, buenos dias, de que forma se guardaria la imagen?

Comment: Esque investigue pero me confundo porque unos utilizan una cosa y otros otra

Comment: Si el usuario desde su dispositivo va a guardar imagenes en su base de datos, debes convertir tu bitmap a una cadena base64 y enviarlo a tu MySQL. Si lo que va hacer tu app solo es consultar imagenes, debes tener tus imagenes guardadas en una ruta y consultarlas desde tu dispositivo a traves de una URL

Comment: Gracias por tus respuestas

Comment: Si mi respuesta te ayudo marcala como acertada por favor, saludos y exito

Comment: Ya le di clic a tu respuesta :3. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

A partir de la ruta:

```
String path = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/images (10).jpg"
```

Crearias un archivo mediante la clase File:

```
File f = new File(path);
```

#### Lo mismo para una ruta de una base de datos:

```
 String path = "/storage/emulated/0//Android/data/com.mydblib/databases/test.db"
 File f = new File(path);
```